# searching file existence at any depth in bash

Tags: bash, shell, file, grep, find

I need to check if a file exists in directory using bash. I have tried below method but it needs complete path as input.

```
if [ -e /*/my_file.txt ] ;
then
  echo "file found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Is there any way that I can check if the file exists at any depth dynamically.
NOTE: I don't want to use "find" as it takes lot of time to execute.

Comment: Why do you think Bash will be faster than `find`, which is specially built to... "find"?

Comment: What is *"a lot of time"*? How many files do you have in your directories? What parameters did you use with `find`?

Comment: say I have 10k files in a system, using 'find' will take approx greater than 1min which is costly for me.

Comment: @fedorqui because in bash find '-e', we need to specify depth in order to find whether file exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, you can write patterns that recursively descend a hierarchy:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in /**/myfile.txt; do
    if [[ -e $f ]]; then
        found=1
        echo "File found"
        break
    fi
done
if [[ $found -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "File not found"
fi
```

Using `find`:

```
found=$( find / -name myfile.txt )
if [[ -n $found ]]; then
    echo "File found"
else
    echo "File not found"
fi
```

Comment: `if [[ -e "$f" ]]`, I guess?

Comment: If you want, sure. There is no *need* to quote a single parameter expansion inside `[[ ... ]]`, though.

Comment: Mmm but what if the file name contains spaces? I tested `touch "a b"` and `[[ -e a b ]] && echo "yes"` returns an error.

Comment: Parameter expansions inside `[[ ... ]]` don't undergo word-splitting or pathname expansion. That's one difference between `[[ ... ]]` (which is a special `bash` construct that is treated differently from regular commands) and `[ ... ]` (which *is* just a regular command). There is a big difference between `[[ -e a b ]]` and `f="a b"; [[ -e $f ]]`.

Comment: Ah right, I wasn't aware of this. Very interesting, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks chepner and fedorqui for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If really speed is your concern, file globbing like `ls * */* */*/*` is not helping you that much. And it has its limit with this error: Argument list too long. `find` is a useful tool for finding stuff. It is very flexible. But like using file globbing, it has to scan the directory tree with every invocation. For occasional searches, like for maintenance, this is totally acceptable. But if this is part processing pipeline, the speed is not acceptable. You need an optimised database for that.

### The simplistic way

Most every UNIX I know is shipped with `locate`.

If it is preinstall you can search like this:

```
$ locate -b '\my_file.txt'
```

The backslash in front of `my_file.txt` is intended. It switches off wildcard search. Adding `-i` gives case insensitive search.

If the command is not available it should be installable from your OS repository. For Debian/Ubuntu: `apt install locate`. For first init run `/etc/cron.daily/locate` as root or with sudo.

The database is updated on a daily basis. For some applications, this interval is probably too long. By moving the cronjob from daily to like every 3 hours, you get more recent results.

### The realtime way ...

This is a bit out of the scope of this answer. But you would need some kind of deamon, that would watch kernel inotify events for directory changes. These in turn would be reflected in a database, that can be queried through some API. Like Spotlight from MacOS or Tracker from Gnome.

Answer (score -1):

`find` is the proper solution.

however you can use bash expansion feature

```
if ls */* | grep -q my_file.txt
then echo file found
else echo file not found
fi
```

note

- that above solution will not find `my_file.txt` if a top level.
- if `my_file.txt` is part of a directory name you might get a wrong result.
- if there are many (thousands) directories and many files */* expansion might get paste bash limit (arg list too long)
- you can `ls * */* */*/* | grep` with limit state above.

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstion Archemar. Its really faster search option to find the file existence.

Comment: used ls / | grep -q my_file and i can see the performance improvement.